# How to pipe commands in rust?

Tags: shell, rust, command-line, command

I am trying to execute a command in a shell and get the return value as a string.
The command I'm trying to execute is `ps axww | grep mongod | grep -v grep`.

I've seen solutions over the internet, but they don't explain the code, so it is hard customising it to my needs.

example: [how to do a sandwich pipe in rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68323175/how-to-do-a-sandwich-pipe-in-rust) & [Pipe between two child processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70205473/pipe-between-two-child-processes)

Can someone please provide a solution and go line by line explaining how it works in layman's terms.

Comment: Note: to avoid grep catching it self `ps axww | grep [m]ongod`

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor lol I never though about that, but indeed it was that simple all the time. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor thanks for the heads up. I got the cmd off the internet... it did seem fishy to me but it worked so... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Just to explain what that does: `grep -v grep` will find everything that does not contain `grep`. Since you look for all process that contain `mongod`, this will also catch the command you are using to do so (so basically this will prevent showing you the command you are typing).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you need is [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/index.html#handling-io), where they do explain everything line by line, with thorough examples. Adapted from it, here is your code

```rust
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};
use std::str;

fn main() {
    let ps_child = Command::new("ps") // `ps` command...
        .arg("axww")                  // with argument `axww`...
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())       // of which we will pipe the output.
        .spawn()                      // Once configured, we actually spawn the command...
        .unwrap();                    // and assert everything went right.
    let grep_child_one = Command::new("grep")
        .arg("mongod")
        .stdin(Stdio::from(ps_child.stdout.unwrap())) // Pipe through.
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .unwrap();
    let grep_child_two = Command::new("grep")
        .arg("-v")
        .arg("grep")
        .stdin(Stdio::from(grep_child_one.stdout.unwrap()))
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .unwrap();
    let output = grep_child_two.wait_with_output().unwrap();
    let result = str::from_utf8(&output.stdout).unwrap();
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

See the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=96ac0a53b5b2a16f0a175f537c7fd793) (which of course won't output anything since there is no process called `mongod` running...).

Answer (score 0):

Rust is just splendid language that makes people think creatively. It is not just like C that designed elegantly and carefully so we could just blindly follow.

```
use std::process::Command;

fn exec(cmd: &str, args: &[&str]) -> String
{
   let output = Command::new(cmd)
   .args(args)
   .output()
   .expect("failed to execute cmd");

   String::from_utf8(output.stdout).unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    let ret = exec("sh", &["-c", "ip addr |grep global"]);
    //let ret = exec("sh", &["-c", "ls -l |grep target"]);
    println!("exec: <{}>", ret);
}
```